How to prevent Dataframe from interpreting a value as scientific notation
I have an ID column in Google sheets which is alphanumeric.  I am reading the values from Google sheet using Pygsheet into a dataframe.  My problem is that when I use the Pygsheet function get_as_df(), some values in the ID column are incorrectly recognized to be in scientific notation and the values that gets read into dataframe show up as "inf".  For example, ID 34E94591 is changed to "inf".  There are no issues if the ID is, for example, 773E893E88 or is just numbers.  I don't think the problem is with the get_as_df() function of Pygsheet but in how pandas is interpreting the values.
Here is the sample code using just pandas
x = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [34E94591, 122322, "773E893E88"]}, dtype=str)

x.head()





Id




0
inf


1
1212454


2
C33432D32



I would like to get




Id




0
34E94591


1
1212454


2
C33432D32



Thank you for looking into this.

In your example, it's python that's reading the value as scientific notation, because you didn't put it in quotes (so it was never a string, and has nothing to do with pandas dataframe or pygsheets). With pygsheets, you need to show the exact call you're using, particularly the value render parameter ; https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html#pygsheets.Worksheet.get_as_df

I strongly recommend you provide a [mre]

Thank you @MatBailie.  After going through the pygsheets doc I passed numerize=False to get_as_df()
